# My body was about to explode in sudarshan kriya (सुदर्शन क्रिया)?

Tags: kriyayoga

I did "sudarshan kriya"or "सुदर्शन क्रिया" couple of days back in presence of a trainer, And suddenly entire body was bursting with energy and feels like body is going to explode.

Later on when I asked him he explained that due to our emotions our breathing pattern changes, which is also reversible means if we breath in a defined pattern body will explode with emotions.

But i still do not understand but really happened?

Comment: Is this Yoga technique  for advanced level Yogis only or anyone can try them as well?

Comment: Yes any one can try but it is a very powerful Yoga technique which should be done only in presence of a trainer.
i have experienced sensation and tingling in body in simple meditation before but this was something else. My hands were airs, every cell in body was vibrating and it scared hell out of me, so i did not give my 100% as i was scared of going in that dimension.

And they told first time experience is the most powerful, emotions may come some people laugh some cry but i was busy observing what was going on inside of me

Comment: you can go to a simple 3 days course in any center of **art of living** and ask where they will be doing sudarshan kriya (सुदर्शन क्रिया) or not.

It will be an exciting experience

Comment: Rishi,no thank u..i don't want my body to explode at this young age..haha..i have so many things still to do..

Comment: lol you would not explode, may i was scared.
But **there are definitely tons of mystical things inside body and infinite outside.**

Comment: Yeah that's true ...:)

Comment: @Rickross I feel that you must be doing at-least something about going deeper in spiritualism, if yes then try "drink you food and chew your water".

It works really well

Comment: Ok ..thanks..i'll try chewing water at least..becoz drinking the food mite be problematic for me..:)

Comment: Essence is "Your entire life even your success depends on how you eat, so when you eat for 10-15 minutes just eat, focus on chewing your food atleast 50 times , the saliva in your mouth sends signals to brain that prepare bla bla acids in stomach in advance and after all the food becomes us, so eating is important

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://www.artofliving.org/faqs-sudarshan-kriya) on Sudarshan Kriya. Sri Sri said: The body has a particular rhythm. Life has a particular rhythm. Similarly, your breath also goes in a particular pattern. Your emotions move in a particular rhythm, as well as your thoughts. All these rhythms arise from your Being, which has its own rhythm.

In Sudarshan Kriya we get into the rhythm of our Being and see how Being is permeating our emotions, our thoughts, our breath, and our bodies. Soon, every cell of the body becomes so alive and releases all the toxins and negative emotions it has stored from times past.

I hope its helps you.